# JTable Automatic Empty Value Reading Issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am reading values of Second column from JTable . Everything works perfectly until it comes to last row. When I am reading the value of last row from the second column, it reads the empty string from the cell. I have invested my complete day to find the solution of this problem, but unfortunately result was unexpected.

Code is given below.

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int rows = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
String strArr[] = new String[rows];
int count = 0;
System.out.println("Rows : "+rows);
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<3; j++){
        if(j==1){
            System.out.println(" i : "+i+" \tj : "+j);
            strArr[count] = (String)tableModel.getValueAt(i, j);
            System.out.println("Value \t: "+(String)tableModel.getValueAt(i, j));
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Table from where I am reading the values:

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: hmm, I answer first and I gave you the code that shows how to stop cell editing and yet you "accepted" the other answer that gave you no details?

Comment: It was up side.. I thought his reputation is lesser.. BTW, Now you happay, @camickr Sir. (*_*).

Comment: @KetanSachan, the point of "accepting" an answer is to "accept" the best answer that provides the information needed to solve the problem. Then people that search the forum can also benefit. *I thought his reputation is lesser.* - you don't reward people for posting a duplicate answer. I provided my answer 8 hours before the other answer was posted. There is no need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your editor is still active so the value you typed into the editor has not yet been saved to the TableModel.

In the ActionListener of your button you need to add logic like:

```
if (table.isEditing())
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

Or, when you create the table you can use:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Check out: [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for more information.